# Should rants be edited out of answers

Tags: discussion, edits

[This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/100490/46732) on Security.SE correctly answers the question, but then goes into a mini-rant (about 60% of the answer's content) about bad security practices that really contribute nothing more to the Q/A.

Should said rant be edited out of the answer? A moderator thinks so, but according to upvotes on the comments, the Security.SE community seems to disagree, and thinks the rant should be left alone.

This, I think, applies to the whole network and not just Security.SE.

*What do we do when an answer answers the question, but has a miniature rant that contributes nothing more*?

Comment: @James Done, sorry that was a blind copy/paste error on my part.

Comment: The rant is well-written and informative, I don't really see a problem with it.

Comment: Guess you never read the [most famous rant on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583) then ;)

Comment: @Oded Oh I've read that one, and I think it's hilarious :P but that was several years ago when the community and 'appropriate content' were a lot different :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've intentionally not read the specific answer yet as there can be a general approach to this.

> Should rants be edited out of answers

It entirely depends on the definition of "rant" (which can be a little subjective) and what the rant content itself is.

Also, it's about "content", rather than how the content can be "labelled" such as "rant", so I'd say leave it in place if the "content" (a.k.a. rant):

1. Is on topic
2. Is useful
3. Adds validity to the answer
4. Isn't rude or insulting to someone, or has profanities etc
5. Is essential in some way to the answer

If it's rude etc then edit it out, as we only want clean and friendly content.

Otherwise, if it's just a useless block of text which won't help anyone then perhaps suggest to the answerer to edit it out, or you can do it yourself - they can always edit or roll back.

Going by the basic definition of "rant", a rant is still content, and might be of use to someone as a way to show (eg) a bad experience with something, but otherwise it's probably just noise and won't be useful.

Comment: Based on the criteria you've suggested, the rant is definitely on-topic. I was just curious as to what the general approach was regarding things like this, so thank you.

Comment: Well, that's just my opinion of course. There are millions of us, and some might believe never to edit other's answers to remove their "content" and some might agree to remove "noise".  some will argue it's a rant and others disagree. That's why I posted a general idea, rather than an opinion on the exact answer :)

Answer (score 7):

You write:

> "the Security.SE community seems to disagree, and thinks the rant should be left alone."

I think you are starting from a mistaken premise.  I don't see any convincing evidence for that.  You might be right, but you might not be -- I don't think there's any way to tell, given the information currently available.

If you are inferring that from the upvotes on [this comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100481/if-a-provider-sees-the-last-4-characters-of-my-password-can-they-see-it-in-full/100490#comment173713_100490), Don't.  That's not an effective way to gauge community sentiment.  Right now there are 11 upvotes, but you don't know who those are from.  This looks like a question that hit Hot Network Questions, so odds are that it got a lot of views from folks who are not regulars on Security.SE, and you can't tell anything about what the Security.SE community thinks from those 11 upvotes.  Also, comments can only be upvoted, but not downvoted, so you have no idea how many viewers were thinking "this rant really ought to be deleted".

In short, you have no information about community sentiment, so don't make assumptions.  You should instead figure out what is the right thing to do, without trying to rely on such unreliable indicators of community sentiment.

Last: if your question is primarily about this specific situation and what to do with this specific question, you would probably be better off asking on Meta.Security.SE.